# Why is there more than 16 combinations for boolean functions with 3 inputs?

Tags: combinatorics

There are $2^{2^{n}}$ possible boolean functions of n inputs. 
But for n = 3, I can only write down 16 and cannot go further.

8 of

$f(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})=0$

and 
8 of

$f(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})=1$

As $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3} = 0 \text{ or } 1$

That's the maximum I can go. What else can it have?

Answer (score 2):

For every function, there are $2^n$ inputs. For each input, you can choose between 2 outputs. Hence there are $2^{2^n}$ such functions.

A way to consider a function would be to consider the values of the following 8 expressions:

$f(0, 0, 0), f(0, 0, 1), f(0, 1, 1), f(0, 1, 0), f(1, 1, 0), f(1, 1, 1), f(1, 0, 1), f(1, 0, 0)$

Answer (score 2):

Think of a Boolean function as a logical operator. This way we can use truth tables to represent Boolean functions. Now, each proposition input into the operator is either true (1) or false (0). There are therefore $2^n$ combinations of truth values for $n$ propositions.

We can think of a Boolean function as a set of outputs for all possible inputs. If we have n propositions as input, there are $2^n$ possible combinations of truth values inputs. Therefore, each function is a binary number with $2^n$ digits, representing the output for all $2^n$ possible inputs.

Because there are two possible outputs for all Boolean functions, given m possible inputs there are $2^m$ possible functions. However, $m=2^n$, and so there are $2^{2^n}$ possible Boolean functions of size n.

Consider this table of all the binary functions f(p,q):
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
p&q&f1&f2&f3&f4&f5&f6&f7&f8&f9&f10&f11&f12&f13&f14&f15&f16\\
\hline
0&0&0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1\\
0&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&1\\
1&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
\hline
\end{array}

Now, consider $n=3$. We would have to add a third input into our table. We would then have $2^3 = 8$ possible inputs. This would mean that each function can be represented by a binary number of 8 digits. There are $2^{2^3} = 256$ possible binary numbers of 8 digits.

Select any number between 0 and 255. Now convert it to binary, and you have a 3-ary Boolean function.